# is it possible to make a console application in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've been asked to make a console application that calls some API. And to modify the data and display it on console when some command is run. Will that be possible to be done in angularJS and how to approach it? if not, what about Angular6 ?

**Please stop down voting this question. I can't delete it as it has been answered.**

I'm a beginner and I need the points to ask other question

Thanks

Comment: Undo the acceptance of the answer and you should be able to delete the question.

Comment: you might like electron JS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angularjs/Angular is to build Web/Mobile Application mostly which runs on client side. You can build console application with javascript/typescript with [`nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Thanks, I though so as well. I spent time googling it and couldn't find any resources confirming that there is no way. Thanks again :)